# Best pattern to rerender my react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a global `data` object I update and then I call `React.renderComponent()` again on the **top/main** component.

Is this the right pattern for triggering this update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally pass the data object into the component as a prop, even if it's a global variable.  This lets you test the component, and also use it elsewhere without being tied to that global.

As Mike said, there's nothing wrong with using `React.renderComponent` to update it.

He also mentioned **flux**, but that's overkill for this.  A simple **event emitter** where you do something like `.emit('change', newData)`, and the component is listening for the change event tends to be better for simpler cases.  See my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25335645/1074592) for an example of  how that can be done.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct pattern.  `React.renderComponent` will either *mount* a component for the first time, or get an already mounted component to *update*.

If you're using a global object though, you might want to look in to the `Flux` architecture here:

http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and asked myself if I really needed to re-render the component.

You can do so with `this.forceUpdate()` but it's not advisable. As [*React* docs states](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> You should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient.

So what I did was create a `data` property like `exists` and test it:

```js
// renderDeleteButton() is being called on render()
renderDeleteButton () {
  if (!this.props.store.exists) {
    return;
  }

  return(
    <DeleteButton
      ...
      deleteAction={this.delete} />
  );
}
```

Whenever I delete/save, I toggle `exists` and component will show up or hide based on that. React handles that for me.